# Will it be annoying for my referee to submit recommendation letters for multiple institutions?

Tags: graduate-admissions, graduate-school, recommendation-letter

I am currently applying for multiple graduate art programs in the UK, and I asked a former professor of mine to write me a recommendation letter. However, because I am applying for quite a lot of schools (specifically eight but all similar programs), will it be annoying for my referee to submit the letter for me over and over again (since they all have their individual website)? Or is it appropriate for me to ask my professor to send me the letter directly, and I submit it through my own application portal instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your reference(s) might have an opinion about it, in particular whether you are applying to too many programs or not. In general, if a professor accepts writing a recommendation letter, then they expect that there is more than one school to which the student is applying. Also, the application portals are in generally built to make submission of letters of recommendation as easy as possible. The reference just has a generic pdf of the recommendation. The portals allow the reference to upload with a very few clicks. Of course, the reference is free to write more specific letters and express their estimate of your capabilities in the application portal.

Answer (score 1):

It is appropriate to ask for letters, and professional academics would realize you need to apply to many universities to win a good position.

Nevertheless, some professors may be a bit lazy, and a bit annoyed, but they wouldn't blame you, rather the system, for this annoyance, so you shouldn't worry about that.

As for sending the letter directly to you, it depends on the system and university, but for most places this is not appropriate or not possible.